# How to get current Windows theme name?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the current Windows theme name in C# but it has turned out to be a little tougher than expected.  I have a code sample from MSDN:

```
public void Test()
{
    StringBuilder themeFileName = new StringBuilder(0x200);
    GetCurrentThemeName(themeFileName, themeFileName.Capacity, null, 0, null, 0);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(VisualStyleInformation.ThemeFilename);
    if (string.Equals("aero.msstyles", fileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // user is using aero theme
    }
}

[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetCurrentThemeName(StringBuilder pszThemeFileName, int   
    dwMaxNameChars, StringBuilder pszColorBuff, int dwMaxColorChars,
    StringBuilder pszSizeBuff, int cchMaxSizeChars);
```

GetCurrentTheme() does not modify the StringBuilder.  I also tried looking at the
System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleInformation class, but it is full of empty values.  Anyone know how to do this?  I must be missing something easy, but I haven't found anything yet that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/uxtheme.aspx) describes how to get "the current visual style information" (search for that string in the article).

It contains sample code how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing the string builder by reference.

Comment: Well, the reference is passed by value.  i did not think that the function would change the referenced object.  I will try that when i get a chance, thanks.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.