# How to detect aero basic theme

Tags: aero, aero-glass, dwm

I can have Windows 7 theme (transparency in title bar) and Windows 7 basic theme (no transparency). How can I differentiate between them? Is there any API which can tell me if glass effect has been enabled. I am currently using `DwmIsCompositionEnabled()` but it returns false when my theme is Windows 7 Basic.

Comment: Basic themes doesn't have glass effect and i think it's right behaior for this function. What's wrong with this function for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Windows theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479421/get-windows-theme)