# From Qt, under Win7, how to know which window style is used for display?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

I'd like to workaround [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46028). So I need to know if user display configuration under Window7 is using "Aero" or "Classic" style.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried `QApplication::style()->objectName()` but this alsways returns me `"windowsvista"` whatever style is selected....

Comment: You need to use WinAPI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479421/get-windows-theme

Comment: It works! Thanks. Any QT based solution for that?

Comment: I think there is no. It's very rare that Qt has platform-specific methods.

Comment: OK. You may want to post this as a real answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with WinAPI. In case of Windows 7 (and possibly Vista, 8 and 10):

```
// true == Aero theme, false == Classic theme
bool isAeroEnabled()
{
    HMODULE library = LoadLibrary(L"dwmapi.dll");
    bool result = false;
    if (library) {
        BOOL enabled = false;
        HRESULT (WINAPI *pFn)(BOOL *enabled) = (HRESULT (WINAPI *)(BOOL *enabled))(GetProcAddress(library, "DwmIsCompositionEnabled"));
        result = SUCCEEDED(pFn(&enabled)) && enabled;
        FreeLibrary(library);
    }
    return result;
}
```

For older Windows versions please follow to [Get Windows theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479421/get-windows-theme) question.