# How do I get the mode (Light/Dark) of the PC in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am currently working on a WPF app. I've noticed that the new windows update brought some cool features, one of them is dark mode. When I set my PC to dark mode, Google Chrome and Firefox became dark as well. I'd like to know how it actually happens and how can I find the current mode via C#.

Answer (score 0):

Light/dark are themes. You could check  the registry [Get Windows theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479421/get-windows-theme)

If that isn't an option.

You could get the colour of a wpf system brush and check it's value.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/wpf/systemcolors-reference/

Comment: Thanks man! I've decided to check the registry.